# Number of Specific Characters Per Every One Million

Tags: python, split, character

First off, I am using Python.

I am attempting to find the number of specific characters (base pairs) per every million characters within a chromosome.

For instance:

I would like to have the number of times a, g, t, and c, and A, G, T, and C appear within the imported file.

I am able (so far), to count the number of these characters for the entire file using "Counter", but am not familiar with how to break this up per every one million?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. But can't you simply divide the resultant number by 1 million?

Comment: Or ... divide by the total and multiply by one million.  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I cannot divide the resultant number by one million as that would give me the average and not the specific number of characters in the first million.

Comment: Sorry if it is a bit vague, I'm a bit new to programming!

Answer (score 0):

If import file looks like the sequence of characters:

> agtcAGTCagtcAGTCagtcAGTCagtcAGTC...

then you could apply this approach:

```
file = 'c:\\test\\chromosome.txt'

aCount = []
gCount = []
tCount = []
cCount = []
ACount = []
GCount = []
TCount = []
CCount = []

step = 1000000
start = 0
end = step

with open(file, 'r') as chromosome:
    data = chromosome.read()

while end < len(data):
  aCount.append(data.count('a', start, end))
  gCount.append(data.count('g', start, end))
  tCount.append(data.count('t', start, end))
  cCount.append(data.count('c', start, end))
  ACount.append(data.count('A', start, end))
  GCount.append(data.count('G', start, end))
  TCount.append(data.count('T', start, end))
  CCount.append(data.count('C', start, end))

  start = end
  end += step
```

At the end you will get 8 lists. Each list will containts counts of occurences of specific characters per million.